# bitcoin-cli "getbalance" always returns 0

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, client

I have bitcoind running on windows and currently it's syncing the blockchain. Nevertheless, command getbalance always returns zero as value. Even if I seach for an address which has bitcoin.

```
E.g.
C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon>bitcoin-cli.exe getbalance "[address...]"
0.00000000
```

Why does it always return 0? I would like to get the address balance of a specific address. I used an address from blockchain.info which had a balance before the current downloaded block.

Answer (score 1):

`getbalance` only applies to addresses you own (and are in your `wallet.dat`).

Comment: Better: it only applies to the balance of your whole wallet. It doesn't take an address argument as input (only deprecated account names).

Comment: Can I search for addresses which are not in my wallet? Like check payment of address x?

Comment: No, Bitcoin Core doesn't maintain the expensive indexes for that.